# Try to get details from AWS beanstalk configration files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am adding SNS to applications on AWS Beanstalk. I want to know which SNS topics the application/environment is attaching to. I tried

```
aws --region us-east-1 elasticbeanstalk describe-environments
```

It only gets a very vague file telling me the app is associated with one sns but no name no arn. Also, my ARM role has no access to the AWS Configuration.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The command actually shows the detailed configuration info.